# SQL Server Replication w/o network connection

Tags: sql-server, backup, mirroring, replication

Is there a way to use SQL Server Replication without a network connection?

My would-be publisher is an SQL Server 2005. It is on the "outside" as it is connected to my company's primary LAN, which is connected through a firewall to the Internet. My would-be subscriber, however, is an SQL Server 2012 that is on the "inside" - due to security reasons, it must be connected to a network that is completely (i.e. physically) isolated from our primary LAN and the Internet. I need a way to replicate outside server changes on the inside on a daily basis.

Is there a way to use Replication without a network connection between publisher and subscriber (e.g. via an optical-disc-based file transfer)? Our security protocol allows for media to be brought inside from the outside, but any kind of communication from inside to outside is forbidden. Ideally, I would run a script on the outside server, burn the resulting output to a disc, and then import the changes (be them inserts, updates, or deletes) to the inside server.

It seems Merge Replication is close to providing this functionality, as it is intended to support subscribers with *sporadic* network connectivity, but it doesn't seem to support scenarios in which there is *no* network connectivity.

Further confounding the situation is the fact that due to the size of the database involved (~50 GB), I need a way to only transfer the differential - I would only like to have to burn the daily changes to disc, not the entire DB (thus eliminating Snapshot Replication as an option).

For now, I have both servers on the outside, so I can use network-based Replication for the initial transfer, but once I deploy the subscriber to the inside, this will no longer be a possibility.

I am also open to other means of solving this problem. I have looked into backup/restore solutions, but have run into trouble as I only need to perform this operation on a subset of the data in the DB, and backing up/restoring only a subset of a DB does not seem to be a trivial exercise.

Comment: This sounds more like a ServerFault question. Essentially, you need the two networks to see each other over all of the relevant ports. This probably requires input from dedicated IT/networking people more so than database administrators and developers...

Comment: How about differential backups of the publishing database restored to an internal copy, separate from the subscriber database but on the same "inside" server? You would then have more options, such as normal replication through localhost.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - our customer dictates physical isolation of the networks, so by definition the networks must not be able to see each other.

Comment: Then I don't think replication is what you want.

Comment: @dartonw - I'm experimenting with something close to your solution: I've setup Transactional Replication to produce a separate database on the outside that contains the subset of data I need to bring inside. I'm then running differential backups on that outside, subset DB and transporting the diff backups to the inside. I believe this gives the same flexibility that your solution offers, but does't require transfer of the entire outside DB to the inside...unless there is a nuance of your approach I am missing?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - it's certainly starting to look that way (that Replication is not what I want), at least not for facilitating the transfer of the data from outside to inside

Comment: What does replicating to the second DB server serve? Why not just take diffs on the primary and move those over to the other location?

Comment: @dartonw - One issue with the approach I'm trying is that I'd like to be able to routinely (daily) restore the inside DB from a differential backup, but this requires the DB to be in the recovering state. I can achieve this with a full DB restore and the NORECOVERY option, but this is time-consuming. The alternative is to restore the DB WITH STANDBY. This leaves the DB in a read-only state - this is actually acceptable in my scenario; however, this option can only be used when the server versions are the same (I'm using 2005 and 2012). I'm currently at a dead end with this approach.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Most of the data in the outside DB is not needed on the inside, so I used replication on the outside to create a DB that only contains the tables I want to move inside. This lets me run backups of only the tables I care about without having to get into partial DB backups using different filegroups, etc. The trouble I'm having now is I don't know how to run regular differential restore operations while leaving the DB in a usable (at least read-only) state without running a full restore every time (see my comment above).

Comment: @DanaWheeler - this might be a job for bcp using the queryout option, but only if there are timestamps or some other way to track added/updated rows

Answer (score 2):

If you use log shipping, you can do the copy operation of the transaction log backups manually to take them from one server to the other.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using log shipping, but ran into the same problem I discussed above: because I'm using two different versions of SQL Server (2012 and 2005 for my inside and outside servers, respectively), I cannot leave my "inside" (secondary) server in the standby state, which I need to do because I need at least read-only access between log restore events. I'll have to either upgrade my outside server to 2012 or install a 2012 instance alongside my 2005 instance and use replication to mirror data from the 2005 server to the 2012 server - then log shipping should work.

Comment: btw I think your security policy or your plan to replicate from outside to inside is bogus.  If the policy is to protect data then you have the copy of the data outside of protection, if the policy is to protect against unauthorised change then you are replicating possibly unauthorised change from the outside database!  Either way it must be circumventing the intent of the policy.

Comment: The primary intent of the security policy is to protect data that is _generated_ on the inside. Our customer wants no possibility of accessing inside-generated data from the outside, thus the physical isolation of the networks. At the same time, we need access to the less-sensitive, outside data on the inside as well, thus the need to bring it in somehow without using a network connection.